# Alternative Anti Frame Buster

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

I've been searching for awhile and tried several anti frame buster codes and none of them truly work.
So my question is, can I have PHP or JavaScript scan all the urls and see if it's a redirect and take the redirect url and use it instead of the original url? I'm using an API and I'm iframing links it gives me and the urls keep redirecting my users to their website instead of keeping their stuff in my frame.

Comment: Obligatory reading: [We Done Been ... Framed!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html)

Answer (score 3):

If a site doesn't want to be framed, you can't make it (unless you turn off javascript in the browser).

It's the site's prerogative to determine whether it busts out of a frame, refuses to show it's content if framed or allows it.

There are methods to try to combat frame busting which turns into some sort of war of techniques, but a site can simply render its content invisible if it chooses.  If a site doesn't want to be used framed, it can prevent it.  It is their content after all.  They should have the right to decide how it is or isn't displayed.

In modern browsers as of 2018, the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header appears to be the most reliable way to prevent framing.  This article [Clickjacking Defense Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet) provides a discussion of various other methods for legacy browsers.  Legacy browsers (I'm mostly talking about IE) have some weaknesses that allow an attacker to defeat certain frame busting techniques.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to display another sites content without taking the user away?
As far as I know this is the only solution to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Nothing I know of in a pure browser-based app.

Comment: I don't know of any other options besides only using static screen shots or finding example sites that don't mind being framed.  As I said, if a site doesn't want to be framed, you can't make it.  If the framed sites would cooperate with you, they could allow the framing when the top window is your domain.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. The only thing is, most of the sites I'm framing the redirect that you get sent to doesn't have any frame busting on it. If I could just sniff the url with JavaScript or PHP and print out the src url it would work, do you know if this is doable?

Comment: You deleted your comment that contains a link to the actual site you're asking about so I can't examine it any more.  If there exists a non-frame-busting URL for these sites, then you would just have to manually record what those URLs are and use them in your site/frame. If you meant something else by your last comment, then I don't understand.

Comment: @max_max_mir - How about a summary of that rather than making anyone who wants to know what it means read that long document.

Comment: @max_max_mir - Doesn't that document say that x-frame-options works?  And, it appears to be more widely supported now than what that document indicates.

Comment: @max_max_mir - Sadly, that document doesn't appear to have a date, but I do note that none of the references it cites are newer than 2010 and it refers to MySpace which probably associates a 2010-type date with it (8 years ago).  I think you'd need a newer survey of techniques to know what the state is in current browsers.  For one it appears that the one technique they like x-frame-options is much more widely supported now and I expect that the `location` object neutralizing techniques have probably been patched too.

Comment: @max_max_mir - Here's a much more recent reference (last updated on Dec 2017): [Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet).  It sounds like the x-frame-options is the most reliable way to prevent framing in modern browsers.